# Alignment of entries in a row

Tags: tables

I am not able not create a MWE as the output below is generated using the [Awesome CV](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/awesome-cv/dfnvtnhzhhbm)  template.

[image]

As can be seen, the `1st row`, `column 1`, and `1st title` are at the same height whereas the `2nd row` and `column 2` are not at the same height as `2nd title`. This is happening since the content in the second column is exceeding more than one line. How to make the changes in the following code snippet to have the `2nd row` and `column 2` at the same height as `2nd title`?

The code responsible for the above output is as:

```
\newcommand{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}{2.5mm}

% For elements of honor
\newcommand*{\honortitlestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont\color{graytext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\honorpositionstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont\bfseries\color{darktext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\honordatestyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfont\color{graytext} #1}}
\newcommand*{\honorlocationstyle}[1]{{\fontsize{9pt}{1em}\bodyfontlight\slshape\color{awesome} #1}}


% Define an environment for cvhonor
\newenvironment{cvhonors}{%
  \vspace{\acvSectionContentTopSkip}
  \vspace{-2mm}
  \begin{center}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
    \setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} C{1.5cm} L{\textwidth - 4.0cm} R{2.5cm}}
}{%
    \end{tabular*}
  \end{center}
}
% Define a line of cv information(honor, award or something else)
% Usage: \cvhonor{<position>}{<title>}{<location>}{<date>}
\newcommand*{\cvhonor}[4]{%
  \honordatestyle{#4} & \honorpositionstyle{#1}, \honortitlestyle{#2} & \honorlocationstyle{#3} \\
}

%------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    \begin{cvhonors}
        \cvhonor
        {1st title} % Award
        {text text text text text text } % Event
        {column 1} % Location
        {1st row } % Date(s)
        
        \cvhonor
        {2nd title } % Award
        {This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.} % Event
        {column 2} % Location
        {2nd row} % Date(s)
    \end{cvhonors}
```

The author has defined an environment for `cvhonors`. I think something needs to be changed in the tabular environment defined under the `\newenvironment{cvhonors}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's apparently what the developer of the class wanted, because of

```
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
```

where `m` column type is used.

If you change `m` to `p`, you get

[image]